# Notation for set of tuples whose items belong to specific sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

How would one denote a set of tuples of specific length whose items all belong to a certain set? E.g. the set that contains all $3$-tuples $(x, y, z)$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $y \in \{2, 4, 6\}$, $z \in \{a: a < 0\}$.

In this case, could it be something like $(\mathbb{R}, \{2, 4, 6\}, \{a: a < 0\})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\{(x,y,z) : x \in \mathbb{R}, y \in \{2,4,6\}, z <0\}$$

Per request, the alternative:

$$\mathbb{R} \times \{2,4,6\} \times \{a : a < 0\}.$$

Comment: Alternatively, $\mathbb{R} \times \{2,4,6\} \times \{a : a < 0\}$.

Comment: Thanks @User203940 - would my suggested notation be acceptable as well, out of interest?

Comment: You should incorporate the alternative into your answer.

Comment: @xing I've personally never seen it that way and I would initially interpret it incorrectly, but every person has their own notation.